# A doubt from Herstein text

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Herstein's text the mappping $\psi:G\to\mathcal A(G):g\mapsto T_g$ is said to be a homomorphism where $\mathcal A(G)$ is the group of all automorphisms of $G$ and $T_g$ the inner automorphism corresponding to $g\in G$ defined as follows $T_g:G\to G:x\mapsto g^{-1}xg.$

So $T_{g_1}T_{g_2}$ must be equal to $T_{g_1g_2}$ for chosen $g_1,g_2\in G.$

But $T_{g_1g_2}(x)=(g_1g_2)^{-1}x(g_1g_2)=g_2^{-1}(g_1^{-1}xg_1)g_2=g_2^{-1}[T_{g_1}(x)]g_2=T_{g_2}(T_{g_1}(x))=(T_{g_2}T_{g_1})(x)$ i.e. $T_{g_1}T_{g_2}=T_{g_2g_1}.$

Please help me to identify where I'm getting wrong.

**Added:** The discussion goes as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no Herstein's text (there are several) at hand now, but it is well known the map you mention gives an *anti-isomorphism* and not an isomorphism.

But no problem: just define

$$T_g(x):=gxg^{-1}$$

and we're cool.

Comment: I know the way you have defined it as most of texts introduce it as the way you did. I'm just trying to understand the herstein convention. For your convenience I've added the textual discussion.

Comment: Ah-ah-aaaah!! But look at Herstein's convention to write maps: *to the right of the argument*, just as most algebraists did until some very few decades ago! With this agreement you **must** take functions composition from *right to left*!:$$xT_gT_h:=(xT_g)T_h:=(g^{-1}xg)T_h=\ldots\;\text{etc.}$$ And then yes: the given map, as in Herstein's, is an isomorphism. If we write maps to the left of the argument then we must do as shown in my answer.

Comment: BTW, which one of Herstein's books is the above taken from?

Comment: Topics in Algebra (2nd Edition )

Comment: But using the convention shouldn't the definition of homomorphism be given as follows $\phi(ab)=\phi(b)\phi(a)?$

Comment: Page 68 (Published by Wiley-India)

Comment: Found it, and I've the 1964 edition. Yes, that's the way many of them algebraists wrote back them, and I learned that way in undergraduate's first year. Alas, all that almost disappeared nowadays.

Comment: No @SritiMallick: with that convention the homomorphism definition is $\,(ab)\phi=a\phi\,b\phi\,$ ...write the function to the right **all** the time!

Comment: Well but shouldn't we consider the elements from right to left as $(ab)\phi=b\phi a\phi?$ (since we have written $g^{-1}xg$ instead of $gxg^{-1}$)

Comment: Since Herstein writes functions to the right, he defines the composition of two functions differently. If $\circ$ denotes the usual composition, then $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$. If $\widetilde{\circ}$ denotes the composition way Herstein defines it, then $(f\ \widetilde{\circ}\ g)(x) = g(f(x))$.

Comment: Thus if we define $T_g$ as in your question (by $x \mapsto g^{-1}xg$), then $T_{g_1} \circ T_{g_2} = T_{g_2g_1}$ but $T_{g_1} \widetilde{\circ}\ T_{g_2} = T_{g_1g_2}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Would you please clarify the statement "you must take functions composition from right to left!" in your first comment?

Comment: ...and as you can see from spin's comment, insisting in writing the functions to the left of their arguments *but* doint the operations from right to left can easily lead us to sheer confusion. That's why I'd advice you to write as Herstein shows **if** you're going to consult his book.

Comment: Sorry @SritiMallick, I meant to take composition exactly the other way around: from *left* to right*:$$x(f\circ g):=(xf)g$$

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks so much.